# Internet Explorer doesn't keep default printer settings

Tags: printer, internet-explorer, default-settings, zebra-printer

I have a pc with two printers, one hp that I use to print A4 sheet and a Zebra GK420t.
Users use Zebra to print labels from a web application.
The problem is that internet explorer (version 7 but I have already tried with more recent versions and nothing has changed), doesn't keep zebra settings but it loses them every time I set hp as default printer.
If I look at zebra printer settings from printers and faxes, settings are right (4 inches width and 3 inches height) but if I take a look at printer preferences from 
printer popup that appears before print labels, they change everytime and become 4.09 x 11.69 inches.
If I leave zebra as default printer everything works fine.
I have the same problem also with other A4 printers (Samsung for example) and the behaviour is the same.
O.S. is windows xp pro sp3.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

**edit**
I've found this article

http://support.vendhq.com/entries/20787027-Getting-a-Zebra-label-printer-to-respect-custom-default-print-size

That explains exactly my problem.
By the way I don't have any option in my printer settings to override this behaviour.

Comment: IE takes the default paper size from the default settings of the default printer. I don't think there is any way you can get it to select a different paper size when you switch printers.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. By the way I don't understand why I have a lot of PCs with a laser printer and a Zebra TLP2844 and this problem doesn't occur even switching between printers.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You say "this problem doesn't occur even switching between printers". Do you mean the problem does not happen, or that it does not happen with other applications? Please explain.

Comment: What does the 'Printer Settings' tab for your printer look like? Could you add a screenshot? Which driver version do you use (probably in the 'About' tab)?

Comment: Have you installed the [latest drivers for the Zebra printer](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/desktop/gk420t.html#mainpartabscontainer_ba36=drivers) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A person with a similar problem has found a solution at  this link [www.computing.net - ie7-default-paper-size](http://www.computing.net/answers/hardware/ie7-default-paper-size/57072.html).

He/She found that IE would revert to 5.08mm bottom print margin if an attempt was made for anything below this measument. Your 4.09 may be kicking this very trigger and thus IE reverts to it comfortable 5.08 when you switch printers.

> IE would not set the bottom print margin to anything less that 5.08mm via the page setup menu, it would automatically revert to this number if something smaller was entered. Changing the margins in the registry (hkey_users\\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup\margin_bottom) stuck for smaller margins.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch the Zebra driver to a Generic Text / Only printer driver to resolve this issue.

Comment: Could you provide more details on how to do it and what negative effects are possible?

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone coming across this in 2020; the link in the question is now dead but did contain the solution. This issue still exists in Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10, where when you print it will always use the paper size of your default printer even if you select to use another printer.

The solution in the case of the Zebra is to install the latest driver, and then ensure you select the "Always use drivers settings" option from the Printer Settings tab in the printer properties.

[image]

With this selected the Zebra will always print using the paper size you defined in the settings, regardless of whether or not it is set as your default printer.